# How to search specifically for scientific/scholarly images?

Tags: google-scholar

How to search specifically for scientific/scholarly images, besides using Google? For articles, there is Google Scholar, but, as far as I am aware of, Google Scholar can't search for images. I would like to input the text/subject and get a relevant image.

Comment: Do you have an image and are looking for the source, or are you looking for images that show a particular thing, and you don't have the image?

Comment: If the latter, you probably just search google scholar for the topic, and keep reading hits till you find what you're looking for.

Comment: @ScottSeidman The latter. Currently, I am using the method you mentioned (reading articles) and regular Google searches.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To my knowledge, Google does not have a function to search academic images. Right now, many of those images are embedded in PDFs or in whatever format the journal published their online material. And many of them are locked behind paywalls and thus not really available to the search engine anyway. I suspect these two issues actually make an academic image search engine *almost* impossible - at least one that resembles the standard google image search. That being said, [JSTOR has an image search](https://www.jstor.org/images). This and other repositories of images could be considered "academic" although I think they are mostly humanities focused.

So the only way to find *scientific* images is to do as you are doing - manually read articles and extract the images you need.

Comment: +1 for JSTOR image *search*. Interesting one there though limited